# Java JPA proxy issue

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA(EclipseLink impl) in my java application. The application works find when there is no proxy configured at system level but when I configure a proxy at system level, the application fails at

```
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

and throws the following exception

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unknown proxy type : null
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
... 24 more
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unknown proxy type : null
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:290)
... 25 more
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:290)
... 25 more
```

I suspect that it is trying to access mysql db at localhost via configured proxy and thus failing. But at the system level proxy configuration, I have configured the following IPs as ignored host

`127.0.0.1` `localhost`

and using the following jdbc url

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clharvester" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a proxy you have to use the real IP address of the server machine to connect to the database.

Comment: what server machine? DBServer? It is on localhost... so I tried 127.0.0.1 ip also but no luck...

Comment: He means the actual machines ip as if you were connecting from somewhere else.  127.0.0.1 is just a loop back address.

Comment: OK now you have to check do you any access ip list to the machine. Is there any firewall.